# Rails 3 Cucumber/Webrat fails on simple "Given": did I set up something wrong?

Tags: cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3, webrat

My feature file:

```
Feature: home page links

  Background: I am on the home page
    Given I am on the home page

  Scenario: I visit the about page
    When I follow "About"
    Then I should be on the about page
```

In my paths.rb, I have

```
when /the home\s?page/ then root_path
```

and rake routes gives:

```
    root  /(.:format)         {:controller=>"home", :action=>"home"}
```

When I try to run "bundle exec cucumber", I get the message:

```
undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<HomeController:0xb29583c> (ActionView::Template::Error)
<a lot of crap>
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:16:in `/^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/'
features/home_page.feature:4:in `Given I am on the home page'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/home_page.feature:6 # Scenario: I visit the about page
```

It's a trivial test, but I don't know where to start investigating this failure. Any ideas? Thanks.

---

Also, my Gemfile:

```
source :rubygems

gem "rails", "~>3.0"
gem "haml", "~>3.0"

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'nokogiri'
  gem 'webrat'
end

group :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~>2.0.pre"
  gem "heroku"
  gem "will_paginate", "~>3.0.pre2"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find the warnings anymore, but I think the [Capybara gem](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) is now recommended for use with Cucumber on Rails3.

Okay, after some searching, it may work fine, but take a look at the comments [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/211357). The problem isn't exactly like yours but it could be related.

Comment: No luck with Capybara either; it still gives the same error. 

Regarding the second link, his error was saying that "visit" wasn't defined. I actually had that error, but changing "config.mode = :rails" to "config.mode = :rack" worked. I don't even understand what my error message is trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I did have the same problem once. I thought Cucumber was responsible but look closer, it seems the error lies in your view: `ActionView::Template::Error`

Cucumber uses the test database, if you require seeds for your homepage, they aren't loaded.

In your case, it seems you've written a misunderstood `controller`, maybe while typing something like `params[controller]`

Comment: My app doesn't use databases: should I be running Cucumber with some options to disable the database? If so, how?